# How do I add bold text to my form?

Tags: 2013, jquery, css, form

Using a script editor on my new form I added this script.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("nobr").css("white-space","normal"); // Lets labels wrap
$("input[title^=lbl]").parent().parent().prev().each(function(index){
// Finds the TR that contains the label (change lbl to your prepend convention)
var lblText = $(this).next().find("span > input").val();
// Gets the label text (the default value)
$(this).parent().before("<tr class='ms-SPButton ms-WPAddButton'>" +
"<td nowrap=true valign=top width=100% class='ms-formlabel' colspan=2>" +
"<h3 class='ms-standardheader ms-WPTitle'>" + lblText +
"</h3></td></tr>"); // Adds a TR formatted as label
$(this).parent().hide(); // Hides the default TR
});
});
</script>
```

Now when you hit "New Item" it creates this label [image]

I want to make the text next to the arrow bold. How do I go about doing this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery you can apply the CSS.

```
$yourElement.css("font-weight","Bold"); // $(this).css("font-weight","Bold");
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to do this i found the code snippet above on another site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var control;  

control = findacontrol("your column name");
control.parentNode.parentNode.style.fontWeight="bold";

    });

function findacontrol(FieldName) {

var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
// get all comments
for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
{
  // now match the field name
  if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0)
  {         return arr[i];      }
 }
}
```

This works for column control values in the form.  Not sure if it will work for you but I know it makes my radio button values in my forms bold.  See if you can play with it and make it work for you.

EDIT:

Just like @Anuja suggested, you can use JQuery to grab the element in a document ready.  For SharePoint form fields, you can use the title to grab the element instead of the nasty ID and class it renders.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[title*="columnTitle"]').css('font-weight', 'bold');

});
```

Comment: so i should copy the whole thing and place it after the first line?

Comment: Yes.  Just replace what you have with this code and see if it works for you.

Comment: unfortunately no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the soloution to this questing could help:

> [How to brand my masterpage using provider hosted apps?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113111/how-to-brand-my-masterpage-using-provider-hosted-apps/115241#115241)